# How to do proxy over proxy (2 layers) by using scrapy?

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy, http-proxy

How to do proxy over proxy (2 layers) by using [scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)? I assume here are the http/https proxies.

For example, my local machine -->proxy1 -->proxy2 --> the site I want to crawl.
How to do that in scrapy?

Why I want to do this?

The goal is to hide my ip address. You can think that proxy1 is very reliable, but it was blocked by the site I want to crawl. And the proxy2 is not reliable but have access to the site I want to crawl.

I could do my local machine -->proxy2 --> the site I want to crawl. But because proxy2 is not reliable, so I could expose my ip address to the site I want to crawl. So I want to add another layer before proxy2 to protect it.

Comment: I think this is more like a configuration on `proxy1`, not something that scrapy should know about.

Answer (score 1):

What for? To hide your ip address you can use High-Anonymous proxy. 
The High-Anonymous proxies mask your IP, replacing it with their own. However the servers you go to may still be able to detect your real IP. This is unlikely, but servers that do add code to detect underlying IP addresses can possibly detect your IP.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to hide my ip address. You can think that proxy1 is very reliable, but it was blocked by the site I want to crawl and the proxy2 is not reliable and have access to the site I want to crawl. I could do my local machine -->proxy2 --> the site I want to crawl. But because proxy2 is not reliable, so I could expose my ip address to the site I want to crawl. So I want to add another layer before proxy2 to protect it.